# Need to capitalize the QLabel text at run-time

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qlabel

I am creating a form using PyQT where I need to set the text for QLabel at run-time. 
How can i set it forcefully to display text in upper case always?
I am using Python for development.

Comment: Do you want to capitalize all the words or just the first?

Comment: I want to capitalize all words (basically the complete sentence -> all letters in all words)

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to set its text? You can probably just add `text.upper()` somewhere in there.

Comment: self.formheading = QtGui.QLabel(heading).. this is how I am setting the  text for label.. where "heading" is a variable which is input at run-time.

Comment: works... i set heading to upper before passing it into the Qlabel. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call the [`upper()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.upper) function as shown below:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QLabel()
    w.setText("word".upper())
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Or you can create a custom class

```
class UpperLabel(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text="", parent=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, text.upper(), parent)

    def setText(self, text):
        QLabel.setText(self, text.upper())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = UpperLabel()
    w.setText("word")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```